# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'RunOptions'

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, attributeerror

I'm a beginner. 
I'm working with python - TensorFlow '2.2.0' on python IDLE.

```
run_opts = tf.RunOptions(report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom = True)
```

I got the following error while running the previous code.:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'RunOptions'"
```

however, according to example 18 from this [link](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/90595/tensorflow.RunOptions) on the official page on Tensorflow, there's no error!

what's wrong in my case? How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `tf.compat.v1.RunOptions` instead of just `tf.RunOptions`?

Comment: The link that you cited is using TensorFlow 1 but you are using TensorFlow 2 so either downgrade your TensorFlow version or use `tf.compat.v1.RunOptions` as described by @Anwarvic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a compatibility issue between `tensorflow 1.x` and `tensorflow 2.x`. In other words, the syntax that you wrote works fine with `tensorflow 1.x`. But as you mentioned, you're using `tensorflow 2.2` which is incompatible.

So, you have can solve this issue by either one of the following two options:

- Uninstall `tensorflow 2.2` and install `tensorflow 1.15` which will save you a lot of the headache knowing that the link that you've posted is using `tensorflow 1.13.1` as mentioned in the [README file](https://github.com/georgesterpu/avsr-tf1#dependencies).
- Or you can use `tf.compat.v1.RunOptions` instead of just `tf.RunOptions`.